# Multiple foreign key constraints to the same primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have two tables:

1. `Image` ->  `ImageId`, `ImageBinary` (Id is `int` and auto-incremented)
2. `Customer` -> `Id`, `CardImageFront`, `CardImageBack`

Where `CardImageFront` and `CardImageBack` are `Id`s referencing to the `ImageId` column. The customer will take two pictures of their card: one for the front and one for the back. Both of them will be inserted in the `Image` table with different `ImageId`. Now I need tried to add two foreign key constraints on the `Customer` table (one for `CardImageFront` and another for `CardImageBack`) referencing the `ImageId` column, it says:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint on table 'Customer' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Should only a single foreign key constraint is necessary in this case? Will deleting the `CardImageFront` from `Image` table will also delete the `CardImageBack`? Or is there something wrong with the design?

Code for the `Image` table:

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Image](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BinaryImage] [varbinary](8000) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Image] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Code for the `Customer` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    

    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [ImageFront] [int] NOT NULL,
        [ImageBack] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

Code for FK constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_1] FOREIGN KEY([ImageFront])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Image] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_2] FOREIGN KEY([ImageBack])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Image] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

Error:

> Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 6
> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_2' on table 'Customer' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: Please show your DDL query

Comment: Seems you have probably done something wrong, because based on the design shown you shouldn't be getting that error. So you need to show us the DDL as already asked. Also can an image ever belong to more than one customer? If not you might consider having the refences the other way around i.e. Imagine has a CustomerID column.

Comment: I've added the DDL scripts.

Comment: @DaleK, the ``Image`` table may contain other images not related to the customer. So I can't add a customerID column on that table.

Comment: Sure you can, you just leave it null when its not related to a customer.

Comment: I'm a little bit surprised at the error, it doesn't appear that a cyclic reference exists. However just remove the cascade and when you delete a customer ensure you delete any related images.

Comment: @DaleK, How can I do that? By writing a trigger?

Comment: Just run 2 delete statements at the same time, delete from image; delete from customer.

Comment: Based on googling this issue it appears to be an issue because as far as SQL Server is concerned, the 2 FK columns could in fact reference the same image. And if you don't have control over building the delete statement, then an instead of trigger is apparently the solution. [Link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/)